# Microsoft Teams modify Save button in Connector setup page

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams

I am currently working on the setup page for my custom MS Teams Connector.
For inspiration, I was looking into other companies and one particular thing caught my attention.

Teams usually has at the bottom 2 buttons, like here in my setup page:

[image: Teams Connector Setup Page]

I have no Problem communicating with them using the `@microsoft/teams-js` client SKD and could make my page work like it is now. But I got curious how to do it with custom buttons like other Companies.

For example Trello:

[image: Trello Connector]

Like you can see they moved the buttons up and also have a login button.
I also need to add authentication form my Connector, so I was wondering if its possible to archive a similar layout for my Connector.

For the Setup page I am using web app created with `create react app`

So my questions are:

Is this possible using `react`?
If yes how is it done?

I could not find much documentation regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is by design. Quite a while back we started giving developers more control in the tab configuration flow and allow them to render their own button within the iframe. Everything within that task module is now controlled by the app.